# How do I show inventory quantity instead of availability on product page? (Luna Theme)

Tags: javascript, bigcartel

I am using the Luna Theme in BigCartel. On the product page that includes thumbs of all products, is it possible to show "# in stock" instead of a blank space when an item is active and in stock?